# Unable to apply Division to a LpVariable

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pulp

Hello Everyone,

I am still new to Linear Programming problems and getting the below error while I try to set the cost
variable which uses a 'division' operator. It runs smoothly with a multiplication (*) operator.

```
line_cmn_var= LpVariable.dicts('md_line',line_keys,0,None,'Integer')


cost= lpSum(line_cmn_var[(l,c)] / md_line.loc[l,c] for c in cmn for l in lines )


md_model= LpProblem('production',LpMinimize)
md_model += cost
```

I get the below error while defining the cost
Error
cost= lpSum(line_cmn_var[(l,c)] / md_line.loc[l,c] for c in cmn for l in lines )

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'LpVariable' and 'int'

Thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
cost= lpSum(line_cmn_var[(l,c)] * (1.0 / md_line.loc[l,c]) for c in cmn for l in lines )
```